# Python Curses while Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, curses

I have a multithreaded program written in Python where I have a number of things happening at the same time:

- reading raw data from an external source
- organizing such data into different lists (parsing)
- saving the post-parsed data into mass storage
- some threads being used to flush some buffers from time to time and other optimizations
- displaying parts of such data for real-time monitoring, using Curses.

The program is latency-sensitive, so I really need this to be multithreaded.
I got the curses thread to display correctly what I want to.

The problem is that while I had everything working without the curses thread, I had a "killswitch" in the main() function that terminated all activity at the press of a key.
I have this global variable called "killThreads" that goes into all functions who are called as threads, and all these functions only work as:

```
def oneThread():
    while (not killThreads):
        doStuff()
        ...
```

And then the main function defines the killThread as False, initializes all threads and turns the killThread as True after a raw_input():

```
killThreads=False

thisThread=threading.Thread(target=oneThread)
otherThread=threading.Thread(target=twoThread)

thisThread.setDaemon(True)
otherThread.setDaemon(True)

thisThread.start()
otherThread.start()

raw_input('Press to end the program')
killThreads=True
```

Everything ran fine **until** I ran a thread with the Curses module to display data.
It seems that while the Curses thread is on, it takes over all input commands. I tried to use getch() with no success. All I could do to keep everything running was to establish a timer within the Curses function:

```
def displayData():
    screen=curses.initscr()
    screen.nodelay(1)
    timeKill=0
    while (timeKill<80):
        #stuff is drawn#
        time.sleep(0.25)
        timeKill+=1
```

Could anyone tell me how to go over Curses and get my keyboard input to "reach" the main function and kill all threads? Or do I always have to input to Curses and then make the Curses function alter the killThreads variable? If so, how do I do it (or where do I find the documentation for that)?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Nice to meet you.

I'm trying to accomplish the same today. Look at this solution:

```
killThreads=False

thisThread=threading.Thread(target=oneThread)
otherThread=threading.Thread(target=twoThread)

thisThread.setDaemon(True)
otherThread.setDaemon(True)

thisThread.start()
otherThread.start()

raw_input('Press "q" to end the program')

key = ''
while key != ord('q'):
        key = screen.getch()

killThreads=True

curses.nocbreak(); screen.keypad(0); curses.echo()
curses.endwin()
```

See, `while` will looping very fastly and waiting for `q` button be pressed, before switch your var `killThreads` to `True`.

It is pretty common practice. However, this `while` loop making thousands of idle loops in second, may be there can be more elegant way or better to embed into this `while` loop `time.sleep(0.1)` at least.

Comment: To prevent the while loop to go that fast you can make the `getch` to be blocking by setting `screen.nodelay(False)`.